# Topic of the Fortnight - Oct. 1-14

Tags: discussion, community, topic-of-the-fortnight

## Topic of the Fortnight:

### The topic of the fortnight is Fringe.

This topic was chosen by Izkata, in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5911/topic-of-the-fortnight).

### What can I ask?

Questions as they arise from the new season, as well as old questions you have about the show. Don't forget to tag them [fringe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fringe)

### How else can I help?

Answer the questions that come up, promote the topic on external sites and other SE (where appropriate, no spamming please), and offer bounties on *existing* [questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fringe) about fringe, either ones that haven't got enough attention, need more detail etc. Save your 'Reward Awesome Question' bounties until after the new questions have been answered<sup>1.</sup>

### Why should I help?

Not only are you adding to the questions on stack exchance you're also, hopefully, promoting the site to others.

### What happens after?

After the two weeks we'll have the Fornight of Rewards! It'll be time to reward those who've answered questions with bounties (the Awesome Question Bounties! mentioned above) and picking the best questions, and posting them here.

## The topic begins at midnight (UTC tonight)

Enjoy!

Comment: Please remember that Season 5 doesn't start everywhere at once - here in the UK it doesn't start until 24th October - so *please* remember to mark spoilers appropriately. (FWIW this is the reason I'm opposed to us doing a fortnightly topic based on something that's brand new 'cos not everyone can contribute equally...)

Comment: Added some last night. Do I need to put a comment on mine like this: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24082/what-do-i-need-to-catch-up-on-to-understand-fringe-season-5 ?

Comment: @NikolaiDante no need to, but if you feel it might help, feel free to.